# How to share a WIX Common Project in different Solutions

Tags: reference, wix, shared-libraries

I need to create several WIX installers that references another project in a different solution (i am using visual studio). For sake of ease lets call this "solution X". All my wix installers are in different solutions from each other but they all share this common project which needs to be referenced. Is this possible?

When I create my wix installer it only allows me to reference projects in the same solution.

I cant just copy the project over to my solution because solution X is constantly being upgraded and that would mean we would need to edit the code in many different places.

My company aka the business has decided all the wix projects must be seperated because they reference other specific projects also.

Whats the best way to approach this...

Comment: Solutions and Projects have a many-to-many relationship. A Project is referenced in a solution by absolute or relative path. There is no requirement that a project be in a subfolder (or same folder) relative to a solution file.

Comment: Do you use a version control system? Which?

Comment: I use Team foundation server

Comment: Is there any reason you can't add the common project (without moving or copying it) to each installer solution?

Comment: well yea. its a generic project that the business uses. If i copy it to multiple locations that everytime they want to upgrade the project they will have to do it @ many locations. And they want to avoid that.

Comment: You don't need to copy a project to add it to a solution(s).